# Difference between Launcher and Theme in Android

Tags: android-theme, android, android-launcher

I'm currently working on launcher based Android app,can any one tell me the difference between  launcher vs theme(Which we usually downloaded from App Stores)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theme is the general look of a phone's UI like the shape, size and color of icons the look of the menu, the background photo or color but the Launcher is an application itself a third-party user interface (UI) programs which take over the duties performed by the factory UI.